# Android studio slow performance when working with large kotlin files

Tags: performance, android-studio, kotlin, ide

I have a problem with Kotlin files in android studio. when the file is too large (for example more than 2000 lines), the android studio is not responding and actually, it freezes when I try to work with it.
I should mention that I have no problem with java files it exists only with Kotlin ones. Also, I've increased the IDE RAM but no luck.

I have a Kotlin file with more than 2000 lines and I cannot work it. when I open it, it stuck and freezes, I cannot even close the file anymore, I must quit the IDE and reopen it.

Is there any known issue or a way to solve this problem?

Comment: this discussion can help you https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7sxhig/android_studio_slower_when_using_kotlin/

Comment: @Ashish thank you, but I didn't get any helpful hint about my problem from the topic.